# Compilation output is different between command line and VisualStudio

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, msbuild

I have generated utility, based power shell, which compile our VS2015 solutions.
The problem is that there a few solutions which fails because the ms build cant find part of their references. 
While I compiling them by using Visual studio GUI, there is no problem to compile them successfully. Compilation configuration is equal(Mixed platform|Debug, not clean, Nuget true).

See print screens :

[image: CommandLine]

[image: VS2015]

I am attaching the compilation function :

```
function buildVS
{
    param
    (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [String] $path,

        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [String] $Configuration,

        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [String] $Platform,

        [parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [bool]   $nuget = $true,

        [parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [bool]   $clean = $true
    )
    process
    {
        $msBuildExe = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\msbuild.exe'

        if ($nuget) {
            $nl
            Write-Host "Restoring NuGet packages" -foregroundcolor green
            nuget restore "$($path)"
        }

        if ($clean) {
            $nl
            Write-Host "Cleaning $($path)" -foregroundcolor green
            & "$($msBuildExe)" "$($path)" "" /t:Clean /m
        }

        $nl
        Write-Host "Building $($path)" -foregroundcolor green
        try
        {
            & "$($msBuildExe)" "$($path)" ("/p:Configuration=" + $Configuration) ("/p:Platform=" + $Platform) ("/p:PreBuildEvent=") ("/p:PostBuildEvent=") ("/m") 2>&1
        }
        catch    
        {
            Write-Error "Build compilation Build FAILEDed" + $_.Exception.Message
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have created a test sample with your powershell script for a solution with one project and a reference project. But the power shell works fine, the solution build successfully. So this issue should be related to your project reference, you should provide more info about how did reference your project so that we could reproduce this issue or you can test it with new blank solution, if this issue still persist, you can share this sample to us.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will keep you posted.

Comment: any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue?